# CRC error detection finding the binary number to be divided by polynomial generator

Tags: crc

If the generator polynomial is x4 + x2 + 1 and the data to be transmitted is 10101010 then find the message which the sender needs to transmit also verify the CRC from the receiver point of view.

what will be the binary number that will be divided by the generator polynomial number?

Answer (score 0):

The message with four zeros appended: `101010100000`.